# How to 'register' new elements?

Tags: jaxb

I'm using JAXB as an easy way to configure my applications and do a validation of configuration parameters at start time. This works great for most cases.
Now I would like to make my configuration a bit more flexible and am wondering how to work with interchangeable elements/objects:

Example (dev environment):

```
<email-gateway user="abc" pass="123456">
    <server-list>
        <server name="lorem"/>
        <server name="ipsum"/>
    </server-list>
</email-gateway>
```

Example (production):

```
<email-gateway user="abc" pass="123456">
    <dns-lookup name="gateway.server" type="MX" />
</email-gateway>
```

Example (production extended):

```
<email-gateway user="abc" pass="123456">
    <round-robin>
        <dns-lookup name="gateway.server" type="MX" />
    </round-robin>
</email-gateway>
```

Java code (simplified):

```
public class EmailGateway {
    @XmlAttribute(name="user")
    private String _user;

    @XmlAttribute(name="pass")
    private String _pass;

    @XmlElement(name="server-list")
    private ServerList _serverList;

    boolean sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        for (Server server : _serverList.servers()) {
            if( server.sendMail(_user, _pass, to, subject, body) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a simple (fixed) setup for the dev environment while production needs some flexibility. Because the server list can change it should be retrieved automatically.

Even better is the second approach. The `<round-robin>` will take care of returning a different server from the list every time to avoid the excessive use of same (mostly first) server.

As the `EmailGateway` class does not need to know about the implementation of ServerList I would like to make it more flexible by changing the config XML only. Otherwise I would have to change all classes using `ServerList` when I use a different algorithm for the retrieval of the server list (e.g. a web service or something like a JNDI lookup...)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found a direct solution for this use case I simplified the problem with an indirection by introducing only one new element which works as a delegate for the rest.

Now only the `<server-list>` element has to know about different implementations.

The result looks like this:

```
<email-gateway user="abc" pass="123456">
    <server-list>
        <string-list>
            <server name="lorem"/>
            <server name="ipsum"/>
        </string-list>
    </server-list>
</email-gateway>
```

or

```
<email-gateway user="abc" pass="123456">
    <server-list>
        <dns-lookup name="gateway.server" type="MX" />
    </server-list>
</email-gateway>
```

or

```
<email-gateway user="abc" pass="123456">
    <server-list>
        <round-robin>
            <dns-lookup name="gateway.server" type="MX" />
        </round-robin>
    </server-list>
</email-gateway>
```